# Confidence intervals for ratios of variances of different populations and other confusing stats

Tags: probability, statistics, variance, confidence-interval

I'm trying to solve an old statistics and probabilities exam exercise for my uni. I don't have a lot of time to learn the subject so I'm trying to figure out how to solve exercises from older tests.

The exercise gives you two populations of steel rods, population A containing 4 rods and population B containing 5 rods. The quantity measured for each bar is the weight they can take until they bend, measured in tons. For A, the mean is 18.6 and the standard deviation is 1.8, for B the mean is 17.8 and the standard deviation 2.1.

The first question requires you to find a 95% confidence interval for the ratio of the variances of populations A and B.

The second question asks you to check the hypothesis that the mean for bars of type A is higher than that of type B for 99% confidence (I am less than 99% sure I am confident in my understanding of what this means).

The third question gives you that A follows a distribution with a mean of 17.5 and a standard deviation of 2. It also gives you that a population of bars is considered acceptable if the mean is above 17, and asks you what the probability of a population of bars of type A to be "acceptable" is.

Now I don't really know much about the subject, I'm primarily just peaking into my textbook to see how to solve this or that exercise. I believe I can figure out how to solve the third question. However I couldn't find how to solve the first two. I know how to find a 95% confidence interval for, say, the mean or the variance or whatever of a population. But how do I determine the confidence interval for the ratio between the variances for two different populations with different sizes? I'm also a bit confused about what the second question wants you to do conceptually. Any help would be appreciated, and will probably help me pass my exams a lot.

Comment: For the first question see [here](https://vrcacademy.com/tutorials/confidence-interval-ratio-variances/) for instance.

Comment: Hmmm alright, however in the test I see you are given F with 3 and 4 degrees of freedom for a/2, but not for 1-a/2. I am however given for some other values and for other degrees of freedom. Is there some kind of property of F that I might exploit to get that?

Comment: What specific value you like to know? Why not looking at a table?

Comment: Because you are not provided with a table. You are provided only a few values. I figured it out by using the property of that distribution where you can flip n and m around and invert the result to get the F for 1-a/2. However I still haven't figured out the rest.